# Redactor JS editor, custom external toolbar solution with plugin

Tags: toolbar, redactor

I'm trying to create a totally custom/external toolbar for [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). So far, I think the best way to do this is to actually turn off the toolbar by default, and create a plugin for it.

I was able to do this successfully wit my custom feature set, but I can't **indicate the state of the text** in my toolbar itself. (ie: **if a user changes the fontSize**, and later on clicks in the middle of the word/sentence, I wanna be able to display that on the toolbar somehow)

Has anybody else run into this?

thanks,
--iM